# Adding custom analyzer to Luke

Tags: java, lucene, luke

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945294/adding-custom-analyzers-to-luke) on Stack Overflow, BTW even after reading the answer provided, I do not manage to add *MyOwnAnalyzer*, so that I can use it directly from  [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/).

Please can someone help me on the right way to do, that is how and what to do so that *MyOwnAnalyzer* can be usable directly from Luke?

Can I do this (it did not work, may be my included jar are incomplete?):

```
java -cp .;d:\java\mylibs\MyOwnAnalyzer.jar -jar lukeall-3.5.0.jar
```

(*MyOwnAnalyzer.jar* was built from Eclipse and contains : *MyOwnAnalyzer.java, MyOwnTokenizer.java, and MyOwnToken.java* inside a subdirectory *com.MyCompany*... Eclipse added *META-INF* and *manifest.mf* for me)

Maybe I am wrong in adding classpath and MyOwnAnalyzer.jar with my command line?

Or must I build Luke from source including MyOwnAnalyzer somewhere in its directory?

Or is there something else to include/write so that my analyzer can be usable and imported from Luke? (looks like there is a mechanism to detect all classes that subclasses Analyzer - MyOwnAnalyzer is already declared as "`extends Analyzer`" )

BTW, even if it not really the same question but still in the same topic of using a custom analyzer from Luke... si I have an Error when using the tab *Analyzer Tool* I get `Error analyzing:com/google/common/io/CharStreams` , this lib is included in a jar, where I included a main that do a sample analysis to check and everything work fine when using it alone. If I use it as explained by JPountz, from Luke, I can see MyOwnAnalyzer from all the Luke tabs, but it did not work!

from the Luke code source, I think what throw the exception this is located somewhere inside the method [analyze](http://luke.googlecode.com/svn-history/r75/branches/branch-3x/src/org/getopt/luke/plugins/AnalyzerToolPlugin.java).

Note: The call to `CharStreams.toString(input);` is to transform the `Reader` input to a String inside `MyOwnTokenizer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java ignores the -cp option when the -jar option is also used. You need to run Luke this way:

```
java -cp lukeall-3.5.0.jar;MyOwnAnalyzer.jar org.getopt.luke.Luke
```

Comment: Thx a lot! It works! i'm new to Java and i do not know that! Classpath troubles are often giving me headache :/

Comment: BTW, even if it not the same question, i have an Error when using the tab _analyzer Tool_ I get Error analyzing:com/google/common/io/CharStreams , this lib is included in a jar, where i included a main that do a sample analysis to check and everything work fine when using it alone. If i use it as explained, from Luke, i can see MyOwnAnalyzer from all the Luke tabs, but it did not work! note: The call to CharStreams.toString(input); is to transform the Reader input to a String inside myOwnTokenizer.

Comment: did you add the JAR containing com.google.common.io.CharStreams (which is Guava I guess) to the classpath?

Comment: well, looks like you continue to point me my numerous misunderstandings... i actually had to had guava to CP... `java -cp lukeall-3.5.0.jar;MyOwnAnalyzer.jar;guava-11.0.2.jar org.getopt.luke.Luke` but, here is my misunderstanding, i already added it to the bundled `MyOwnAnalyzer.jar` and to the classpath bundled inside this Jar, so i was thinking i do not have to add it anymore! so i always had to do so? (or i have missed something?)